# GraphHopper inconsistent routes

Tags: graphhopper

We get one route when running GraphHopper with Contraction Hierarchies enabled and a different route when we disable Contraction Hierarchies. Why is that happening?

A running example can be downloaded from:
https://bitbucket.org/equipemovup/graphhopper-example

Comment: This should not happen. Did you modify GraphHopper? And if not, could you provide the exact example (a lat,lon pair) where this happens? Also please specify the osm file you used (latest berlin from geofabrik?). Also please try if this also happens for 0.4-SNAPSHOT

Comment: No, we did not modify GraphHopper any way. We have tried with lastest GitHub version and with GraphHopper 0.3 version from mnvrepository. Both versions share the same problem. We have used the latest berlin from geofabrik. The lat, lon pairs used were: (52.535926,13.192974) and (52.52651,13.493285). See both implementations in: http://goo.gl/D5GkWA and http://goo.gl/ABa46B

Comment: Your code looks good. I've downloaded and tried but in both cases I get: distance: 23436.698276358577, time:30min, points:262, simplify (487->262). Or what kind of differences do you get? Maybe you provide me with the exact OSM file so that I can try again?

Comment: Our results:
  Without CH:
    distance:22822.119276358575
    points:235
    time(min):30.858083333333333

  With CH:
    distance:23436.698276358577
    points:262
    time(min):29.822916666666668

MD5 (berlin-latest.osm.pbf) = 8bc1765baaa7d1fac818b96368783e11

Comment: Are you running DijkstraBi.java (without CH) and DijkstraBiCH.java (with CH)?

Comment: ah, would you try setWeighting("fastest") for the none-CH case. I've the same pbf here and get the same results for both cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, Karussell! Your last comment solved the problem! So, it works perfectly when we use:  (1) req.setWeighting("fastest") without CH or (2) hopper.setCHShortcuts("shortest") with CH. Our suggestion is that GraphHopper should use the same default behavior (shortest or fastest), when CH are used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly when we use:

```
(1) ghRequest.setWeighting("fastest") without CH
```

or

```
(2) graphHopper.setCHShortcuts("shortest") with CH
```

Our suggestion is that GraphHopper should use the same default behavior (shortest or fastest), when CH are used or not.

Comment: Yes, thanks! We'll fix this! https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/261

Comment: Now defaults to 'fastest' for both cases